# Jquery get input value on input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the input value while I keep pressing keyboard keys.

Following updates the input if I click out of the input field.

```
    $('create-text').onchange = function() {
        console.log("whoo: " + this.value);
    }
```

Comment: And your question is? It should be `$('.create-text')` or `$('#create-text')` or `$('[name="create-text"]')`

Comment: You can use `.keyup` event
https://api.jquery.com/keyup/

Answer (score 1):

The `.change` event triggers when the value has been changed and the element loses focus, as in click outside of the element.

When releasing a pressed key:

```
$('create-text').keyup(function() {
    console.log("whoo: " + this.value);
});
```

When pressing a released key and wanting to record modifier and not-printing keys:

```
$('create-text').keydown(function() {
    console.log("whoo: " + this.value);
});
```

When pressing a released key and not needing the above:

```
$('create-text').keypress(function() {
    console.log("whoo: " + this.value);
});
```

However, you would probably want to use a proper selector `.create-text` or `#create-text` to target your input element. You could also get more specific by using something like `input[name="cr-text"]#create-text`.

Answer (score 0):

```
//  On pressing key
$("input").keyup(function(){
    console.log($(this).val())
});

//  When focus lost
$("input").focusout(function(){
    console.log($(this).val())
});
```